# AppxBundleManifest.xml . Duplicates locales

Tags: c#, xml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I create app packages. In *bundle.appxupload*_x86_x64_arm.appxbundle\AppxMetadata\AppxBundleManifest.xml contains -

```
...
    <Resources>
        <Resource Language="de-de"/>
        <Resource Language="de"/>
    </Resources>
...
```

and so with everyone language :(
I only need one(Resource Language="de"). Prompt please, what should I do to avoid this repetition. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of them is culture-invariant, the other is not. "de" is "German", while "de-de" is "German (Germany)" as opposed to "German (Austria)".

The repetition is there because of the way that AppxBundles work. They generate a separate bundle portion (if necessary) for each language and culture. This may affect you if you have different content for different cultures of a given language. If you do not, then it should not affect you, but you still need those to be marked in the BundleManifest. It's auto-generated anyway, so it's not something that you should have to worry about.

Comment: Thank you. In my application, i use In-App Purchases. I have to fill out information for each culture(de and de-de, en and en-us). I  duplicate for each culture. How i can avoid it? Thanks Again.

Comment: For that I think you may be out of luck. You should be able to copy/paste though (for some of it).